# Сформировать коммит с сообщением на основе указанного коммита

Tags: git, git-commit

Задача следующая: нужно скопировать сообщение старого коммита и исправить последнюю строку в нём для нового коммита.

Сейчас приходится находить нужный коммит, копировать его сообщение, делать новый коммит с таким же сообщением, подправляя последнюю строку. Хочется упростить этот процесс.

Узнал недавно про такую возможность, как `git commit -C HEAD`, которая сделает коммит с таким же сообщением, как в указанной ссылке, но приходится еще делать `git commit --amend`, чтобы подправить последнюю строку.

Можно ли обойтись одной командой для этого?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

изспользуйте опцию `-c`, а не `-C`:

```
git commit -c <коммит>
```

в этом случае сразу можно внести правки в коммит-сообщение.

ещё логично добавить опцию `--reset-author`, для того, чтобы авторство и время создаваемого коммита не дублировались из указанного существующего коммита.

Answer (score 4):

```
git commit -C HEAD -e
```

> -e The message taken from file with -F, command line with -m, and from commit object with -C are usually used as the commit log message unmodified. **This option lets you further edit the message taken from these sources**.

Или как правильно подсказал alexander barankin:

```
git commit -c HEAD
```

Comment: `--reset-author` не достаточно?